# 1d Heat equation with variable Area

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the following pde. It's the 1d heat equation for a rod with changing Area with Neumann Boundary conditions.

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{A'(x)}{A(x)}\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} $$

$T(x,0) = 0$   ;       $\frac{\partial T(0,t)}{\partial x}=R$    ;   $\frac{\partial T(L,t)}{\partial x}=Q$

So far I've been using matlab and pdepe to solve it. However, I need to solve it thousands of times and computational speed is getting in the way of this. I was hopping to find a faster way.
I know that a closed-form solution is impossible to find. I'm still unsure if it's possible to solve it using a series expansion. If $A$ is represented as a Fourier series on a finite domain. I didn't get very far with this.

I had an idea of using separation of variables, to solve the time-dependent terms analytically and to use a numerical solution for my x terms. However, I'm not sure if this is possible as separation of variables would require one of the functions to be periodic.

Any advice on how to proceed would be much appreciated. Maths was never my strong suit, but this problem has really captivated me.

Comment: If your rod changes slowly, i.e. if you know the form of $A(x)$ and it happens to be suitable, you might be able to use either perturbation theory or the method of dominant balance to get a much faster approximate solution. I also wonder if you could use a conformal mapping method of some kind to make your domain rectangular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map . The book "methods of mathematical physics" by morse and feshbach has examples of this.

Comment: Do you have an exact formula for $A(x)$?

Comment: A doesn't have an exact formula It's just areas along the length of the rod that I then linearly interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

use separation of variables $T(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$ and series solution for $f(x)$.

Homogenize the boundary condition at $x=0$ first by :

$T(x,t)=u(x,t)-R$

And solve for $u(x,t)$.

Comment: I have tried this however I end up with an equation of the form $x''+F(x)x'-cx = 0$ If I represent $F = A'/A$  as Fourier series I end up with One Fourier series multiplied by another and I couldn't figure out how to get the coefficients for this.

Comment: Not Fourier series. Frobenius's method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method?wprov=sfla1